# How can I store a number and a corresponding word together in a Java data structure?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I'm not sure if I'm using my arrays in Java correctly. How do I store a word and a number together such that given the number I can select the corresponding word

For example, given that the number two corresponds to the word "Orange":

```
Prompt: "Enter number:"
Input: 2
Output: "Color is Orange."
```

My attempt using an array:

```
String [] colorResList = new String[10] ;
int  resCounter = 0 ;
// Assign values to elements in array.
colorResList[2] = "Orange";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation, keyed by `Integer` with value `String`:

```
Map<Integer, String> colors = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
colors.put(2, "Orange");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a concern that usually is done by using a `Map`; often times a `HashMap<T,S>` will be applicable. For your concern, you could use a `HashMap<Integer, String>`.

EDIT:
If you would like to store it in an array, you can just use an array like you did in your question and do this

```
int i = //read in number here
System.out.println("Color is " + colorResList[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replys! Hmm, the thing is, I have not learned using map yet, so far I only know that I could use methods and I think I'm required to use arrays,I can store integer arrays but I just don't know how to relate them to strings :/

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
Map <Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

map.put(1,"One");
map.put(2,"Two");
map.put(3,"Three");
map.put(4,"Four");

System.out.println( map.get(3)); // get printed "Three"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap(an implemenation of Map interface), like this:

```
Map<Integer,String> m = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
m.add(1,"Orange");
m.add(2,"Blue")
System.out.println("The colour is "+m.get(1));
```